# Поиск с учетом релевантности

Tags: поиск, mysql

Хотелось бы самому написать небольшой скрипт поиска по БД. Все это хорошо реализовать с помощью LIKE %abc%, но как быть с релевантностью? Чтобы полное совпадение было на первом месте, все остальные - на втором. Совет нужен в одном - для этого используется 2 запроса ? Один с точным значением, второй - с LIKE? Или можно как-то все это объединить в 1 запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких целей, лучше бы использовать что-то вроде [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)-а, вместо LIKE - **MATCH AGAINST** (*зависит от определенных условий*). Да и статей по этой теме уже достаточно. Вот,  например, "[Релевантный поиск на php](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128590/)"

Comment: @Deonis. Ок, а я хотел как кулхацкер - все сам организовать. Без статей.

Comment: @Deus, "все сам организовать" - уже не получается. Вы ведь задаете вопросы тут?

P.S. Объясню по-другому... Многие уже задавались этим вопросом и многие, как и я, не любят изобретать велосипеды. В связи с этим, эти многие, рассматривали уже созданные варианты решений, анализировали их и выбирали самый подходящий на их взгляд. Поэтому ответ, который вы ждете, может быть основан на какой-либо хорошей статье, которую вы упорно не хотите читать. И получится, что вам эту стать, будут пересказывать тут своими словами.

Answer (score 3):

Я такой велик делал. Ход работы:

1. Подготовить таблицу к поиску.
2. Преобразовать поисковую фразу в слова/морфемы.
3. Найти *все* совпадения, то есть, даже совпадения по одному слову из фразы.
4. Отсортировать по релевантности.

Под «подготовить таблицу к поиску» я подразумеваю вынос всего контента, по которому мы будем искать, в отдельное поле и правильную расстановку индексов. К примеру, у записи есть заголовок и содержание. Новый столбец обзовем `searchable`. Значит, в новом поле будет храниться `CONCAT_WS(" ", "заголовок", "содержание")`:

```
`title` : "Трое в лодке, не считая собаки"
`content` : "Представляет собой отчет о лодочной поездке по реке Темзе между Кингстоном и Оксфордом..."

->
`searchable` : "Трое в лодке, не считая собаки Представляет собой отчет о лодочной поездке по реке Темзе между Кингстоном и Оксфордом..."
```

Это нужно для оптимизации процесса сортировки.

Преобразование поисковой фразы в слова я делал таким образом, чтобы предлоги и частицы (1-3 буквы; в зависимости от языка) сливались со следующим словом. Это, на мой взгляд, лучший вариант, так как в тексте предлоги и частицы в основном относятся с последующему за ними слову. Но и проблема тоже есть: союз «и», к примеру, нельзя отнести ни к предыдущему, ни к последующему слову. Поэтому, я вырезал все «пустые» слова из поисковой фразы (для каждого языка). Ну и, конечно, знаки препинания — тоже вырезал. Получал, такие «слова»: "Трое в лодке, не считая собаки" -> "Трое | в лодке | не считая | собаки". Или "mysql search in table" -> "mysql | search | in table".

Еще очень важно для нормального поиска — знать, какая часть слова не имеет важности: это приставка и окончание. Суффикс тоже можно убрать. То есть, для нормального-ala-гугол-поиска желательно брать только корни слов. Для этого понадобится какой-то скрипт, который бы смог выдергивать морфемы. И это, хотя и достаточно сложно, но [гуглится](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=php+морфология).

Искать проще всего:

```
<?

$words = search_query_get_words('Трое в лодке, не считая собаки');
// $words : array('Трое', 'в лодке', 'не считая', 'собаки');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ';
$query .= '`searchable` LIKE "%' . implode('%" OR `searchable` LIKE "%', $words) . '%"';

?>
```

Ищем по одному только полю — сгенерированному ранее <code>searchable</code>.

Хитрость заключается в том что, если уже предусмотрен морфологический разбор слов, то колонка `searchable` должна хранить не тупую склейку заголовка и содержания, а только уникальные корни слов из полей `title` и `content` — это сэкономит и объем физической памяти, занимаемой таблицей, и, что важнее — скорость выполнения запроса.

Морфологический разбор слов текста нужно будет производить значительно реже — при редактировании или добавлении новой статьи. Это значительно проще, чем при каждом поиске пытаться адаптировать каждое запрошенное слово с учетом всех склонений-падежей.

Самое главное — правильно отсортировать. Я прикинул, что самым важным в определении того, насколько результат соответствует запросу, является расстояние в символах между найденными словами. Но это оказалось и самым сложным, поэтому я опустил это. Вторым по важности я считаю *количество слов* поисковой строки, присутствующих в записи. А вот *количество вхождений одного и того же слова* в записи — наименее значимо.

Кроме того, очень важно, где именно найдены слова: в заголовке или в содержании.

Итак, есть 2 фактора:

1. количество слов;
2. количество вхождений одного и того же слова.

Получить количество несложно:

```
<?

$words_in_field = '';

foreach ($words as $word)
    $words_in_field .= ' + IF(`searchable` LIKE "%'.$word.'%", 1, 0)';

$words_in_field = substr($words_in_field, 3);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE '. $words_in_field .' > 0 ORDER BY '. $words_in_field. ' DESC';

?>
```

Получить количество вхождений можно вот как:

```
mysql> SELECT (LENGTH("Шел-шел, да упал") - LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER("Шел-шел, да упал"), "шел", ""))) / LENGTH("шел")
```

Итак, есть результаты по двум «факторам» и есть 2 «настоящих» колонки `title` и `content`. Нужно определиться, какое поле важнее. Я считаю, что заголовок — самое важное. Предположим, у нас есть 2 записи (статьи). При запросе, состоящем из 4 слов найдется:

1. Первая статья: в заголовке — 2 слова; в теле — 4 слова
2. Вторая статья: в заголовке — 3 слова; в теле — 2 слова

В этом случае в начале выдачи нужно показать «Вторую статью», а ниже — «Первую статью». Значит, колонкам нужно указать веса. Пусть это будут 1 и 0.5 для `title` и `content` соответственно. При подсчете индекса соответствия нужно умножать количество найденных слов на вес данной колонки.

Конечно, этим не обойтись. Нужно предусмотреть и упростить процесс поиска одного-единственного слова. Рано или поздно встанет вопрос о том, как же сортировать одинаковые по релевантности результаты (ага: PR, тИЦ) или как сделать так, чтобы таких ситуаций не возникало...

Конечно, для огромного объема данных этот вариант очень слаб. Но для внутреннего поиска на средненьком сайте этого вполне достаточно.

- [Пример таблицы](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a08f8)
- [Генерировать SQL-запрос для поисковой фразы](http://www.lotoflot.com/files/search_test.php)
- [Исходник](http://www.lotoflot.com/files/search_test.php?source)

Comment: @Bars, спасибо за содержательный ответ, жаль, что не смогу отметить как правильный!